# HTML-код Vs. интерактивные конструкторы при создании и обновлении сайта

Tags: html

Для создания своего сайта стал изучать `HTML`, `CSS`, `LESS` и `JavaScript` - про конструкторы типа **Wix** и `CMS` типа **WordPress** слышал, но как-то некомфортно, когда не знаешь свой сайт до последнего HTML-тега. Впрочем, исходя из того, что `HTML` изучают многие и по сей день, можно сделать вывод, что метод создания сайта путём набора HTML-кода не собирается уступать свои позиции конструкторам, работающим в интерактивном режиме, а значит, у этого метода должно быть какое-то преимущество по сравнению с конструкторами.

Но стоило задумался о процессе обновления сайта, когда он уже будет создан, сразу стало ясно, насколько будет неудобно добавлять в него новые публикации таким же методом. Насколько я знаю (поправьте меня, если не так), на практике эксперты верстают сайты вводом HTML-кода, а дальше передают его управление заказчику с помощью CMS.

Вопросы у меня такие:

- Какие преимущества даёт метод создания сайта путём написания HTML-кода без использования конструкторов?
- Как поступают эксперты на практике, когда обновляют содержимое созданных ими сайтов? Всё же используют CMS или вручную меняют HTML-код?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё зависит от того, какой тип сайта вы планируете делать.
Для статических сайтов (на подобии сайта-визитки), не требуется CMS, так как количество информации не очень велико, а обновления не являются систематическими (постоянными), поэтому можно обойтись связкой html-css (+javascript).

Если же требуется постоянная публикация какого-либо контента, то тут нужна CMS для более удобной работы. Можно всё делать в ручную, но это крайне неудобно. А на написание CMS нужны дополнительные знания, например, PHP и SQL для хранения и извлечения новостей из базы данных.

Конструкторы рассчитаны на людей, которые не имеют знаний в вёрстке. У конструкторов есть свои плюсы и свои минусы, которые перечислять не имеет смысла. Если вам нужен один сайт, который вы не планируете особо редактировать, то можно обойтись конструктором. Если же вы планируете серьёзно работать над сайтом и, возможно, применять свои навыки вёрстки в других проектах, то стоит начинать практиковать без конструкторов.

Comment: А какую CMS Вы можете порекомендовать для управления сайтом, написанного вручную на HTML? Я сейчас как раз выбираю таковую, но судя по описанию, все они предполагают создание сайта с этапа выбора шаблона. Мне же надо импортировать в CMS свои HTML- и CSS- файлы для дальнейшего управления содержимым.

Answer (score 3):

> как-то некомфортно, когда не знаешь свой сайт до последнего HTML-тега

А свой компьютер Вы до последнего байта знаете?

> исходя из того, что HTML изучают многие и по сей день, можно сделать вывод, что метод создания сайта путём набора HTML-кода не собирается уступать свои позиции конструкторам, работающим в интерактивном режиме, а значит, у этого метода должно быть какое-то преимущество по сравнению с конструкторами.

Возможности конструкторов сильно ограничены по сравнению с ручным способом

> на практике эксперты верстают сайты вводом HTML-кода, а дальше передают его управление заказчику с помощью CMS

Обычно так, но есть и исключение - landing pages